# How would I create this array structure in an HTML form?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following HTML form, which is being generated dynamically from a table in a MySQL database.

```
<form method="post" name="chapters" action="ChaptersUpdate.php">
<input type='text' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'>
<input type='text' name='name' value='{$row['name']}'>
<input type='password' name='password' value={$row['password']};>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

I am looking for a way to make it such that when the form is submitted, the following data structure gets passed in $_POST:

```
 [chapter] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => corresponding chapter ID
            [name] => corresponding chapter name
            [password] => corresponding chapter password
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => corresponding chapter ID
            [name] => corresponding chapter name
            [password] => corresponding chapter password
        )

)
```

I tried various combinations of name='chapter[][id]' / name='chapter[][name]' / name='chapter[][password]' with little success. The array data structure never looks like what I want it to look like.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The following appeared to work for me:

```
<input type='text' name='chapters[0][id]'>
<input type='text' name='chapters[0][name]'>
<input type='password' name='chapters[0][password]'>

<input type='text' name='chapters[1][id]'>
<input type='text' name='chapters[1][name]'>
<input type='password' name='chapters[1][password]'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your form like this

```
<form method="post" name="chapters">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i <3; $i++)
{
    echo "ID: <input type='text'  name='chapters[$i][id]' /> <br />";
    echo "Name: <input type='text' name='chapters[$i][name]' /> <br />";
    echo "Password: <input type='text' name='chapters[$i][password]' /> <br /> ";
    echo "<Br />";
}
?>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Sample PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['chapters']))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['chapters']);
}
```

Sample Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Name1
            [password] => Password1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => name 2
            [password] => password 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => name 3
            [password] => Password
        )

)
```

Comment: Right, so I am actually doing something similar. The PHP component that actually creates these input fields is: while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<input type='text' name='chapter[$i][id]' value='{$row['id']}'>"; } where $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chapters"). Weird thing is, when I check the source code of the actual resulting HTML page, it doesn't show "chapter[1][id]"...it just shows "chapter[][id]". Could that be a part of the problem?

Comment: look at my code you would see `for($i = 0; $i <3; $i++)` ... what is when they are created ..

Comment: ohhhh, so in my case, would the for loop go within the while() loop that I have at the beginning?