# Retrieve a variable whos name is has another variable in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

Dunno if the title makes sense, but I have a variable which would to put it in basic terms would be called like this:

```
$_POST['something'+$variable2]
```

I have a form which is for editing selected records, this form contains entries for all previously selected records:

```
<form name="input" action="editcar.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" value="Yes">

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    {
                    echo'
</div>     
                    <table style="color:white">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right">Manufacture:</td><td><input type="text" name="manufacture'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['make'].'"></td> 
                            <td style="text-align:right">Model:      </td><td><input type="text" name="model'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['model'].'"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right">Colour:     </td><td><input type="text" name="colour'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['colour'].'"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">Reg:        </td><td><input type="text" name="reg'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['Reg'].'"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right">Price:      </td><td><input type="text" name="price'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['price'].'"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">Mileage:    </td><td><input type="text" name="mileage'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['miles'].'"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right">Max MPH:    </td><td><input type="text" name="mph'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['mph'].'"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">MPG:        </td><td><input type="text" name="mpg'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['mpg'].'"></td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>

                </form>

            </div> ';

                }
                ?>
                </form>
```

The form is looped for each record previously chosen, to enable mass editing. The isue arouses when I realised I'd have multiple inputs with the same name, so I did:

```
<input type="text" name="model'.$row['carIndex'].'" value="'.$row['model'].'">
```

Placing the primary key of the record it was currently tired to on the end of it's name. Which seemed like a logical way to go about things.

However now I need to call these variables to place in the mysql query and I dunno how to do that, or even if I can.

I have the selected records saved in an array so I have:

```
foreach ($postid as $carID) 
   {  
      $query = "stuff";
      mysqli_query($db, $query);
   }
```

Each loop has $carID containing the variables that was put on the end of the form input names.

So something like:

```
$_POST['something'+$variable2]
```

is all I can think of but doesn't work.

Any method that works for my overall code is welcome not just a solution to the issue I've made.

Comment: I can only guess from what you posted but to me it doesn't look like you are going to use these variables in a prepared statement. I suggest once you solve your problem you take a look at PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your way should work. Just replace the `+` with `.` in `$_POST['something'+$variable2]`.
My tip is: use an array as name in your html instead:

```
<input type="text" name="model[]" value="'.$row['model'].'">
```

On php-Side you can loop through all `$_POST['model']` since its an array now.

You can add the index for every entry in your html, too:

```
<input type="text" name="model['.$row['carIndex'].']" value="'.$row['model'].'">
```

Comment: Awww yissss, still new and just got mixed up with js and php, I think I'll use the array way, its how I stored the selected records so it does seem like a more elegant method.

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses a dot for concatenation, not + like Java and Javascript:

```
 $_POST['something' . $variable2]
```

Comment: Oh, silly me it does, I'm still fairly new and I've been doing a whole lot of js and jquery etc recently. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<form ...>

<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...):
   $index =  $row['carIndex'];

?>

<input type="text" name="carmodel[<?php echo $index?>][model]" value="<?php echo $row['model'] ?>">

<?php endforeach; ?>

</form>
```

This way you will have the data stored in $_POST['carmodel'] as an array indexed by carIndex value as the structure of data in $_POST is defined by names of inputs, here you will have names likee   carmodel[1][model]    for example so then in post it will be in  $_POST['carmodel'][1][model]

you can read here as well 
[How would I create this array structure in an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557283/how-would-i-create-this-array-structure-in-an-html-form)